# Value won't show in second controller after passing value from first controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I am trying to pass a value from one controller is another. I am loading the second controller into the first and running the setLabelViewPassed() method that is in the second controller. The problem I am having is that when I use the getLabelViewPassed method it does not receive the passed value. I System out the passed value and when I run it the value shows up, so I don't' know what is wrong.

Controller One

```
    package sample.controllers;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ControllerOne {
    private String passedValue;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Label labelViewOne;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton viewOneButton;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        viewOneButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            passedValue = labelViewOne.getText();
            showControllerViewTwo();
        });
    }

    public void showControllerViewTwo() {
        //Get the current scene and hide it
        viewOneButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();

        //Get new view in FXML loader
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/views/controllerTwo.fxml"));

        try {

            loader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ControllerTwo controllerTwo = loader.getController();
        controllerTwo.setLabelViewPassed(passedValue);

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.showAndWait();


    }
}
```

Controller Two

```
    package sample.controllers;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ControllerTwo {
    private String labelViewPassed;


    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Label labelViewTwo;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton viewTwoButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField textFieldViewTwo;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        textFieldViewTwo.setText(getLabelViewPassed());

        viewTwoButton.setOnAction(event -> {

        });
    }
    public String getLabelViewPassed() {
        return labelViewPassed;
    }

    public void setLabelViewPassed(String labelViewPassed) {
        this.labelViewPassed = labelViewPassed;
        System.out.println(labelViewPassed);
    }
}
```

This is simple I know but for some reason, I can't figure it out even after searching. I am just trying to pass the value from from a label in controller one to set the text of a label in controller two.

The Value passed to second controller is printed out but the label does not show this new value.

Answer (score 1):

`initialize()` is called during the execution of `FXMLLoader.load()` (so it is called *before* you call `setLabelViewPassed(...)`).

Move the line that sets the label's text to the `setLabelViewPassed()` method:

```
@FXML
void initialize() {


    viewTwoButton.setOnAction(event -> {

    });
}
public String getLabelViewPassed() {
    return labelViewPassed;
}

public void setLabelViewPassed(String labelViewPassed) {
    this.labelViewPassed = labelViewPassed;
    textFieldViewTwo.setText(labelViewPassed);
    System.out.println(labelViewPassed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple, I'm just learning and mocked this simply project up to help me understand it. Thanks again!